# DAZ Studio animated model to Cinema 4D: how to get it right?

Tags: animation, cinema4d

I am trying to export a DAZ Studio animated model to Cinema 4D while keeping the animation.

**What I tried:**

- Convert aniMate timeline to keyframe timeline;
- Export as .fbx 2012 & .fbx 2014 (binary) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVvPi.png) ;
- Import (merge) in Cinema 4D and play it [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0a92.png).

**Where it fails:**

While everything seems to import properly (including textures, models, rigs, etc.) the animation part produces very weird spaghetti fingers and legs. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIeyC.png)

A few pictures showing my settings and the result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm betting there's something buried in the morph export rules area of the export settings... what you're seeing is what in other 3D DCC apps would be called a bind error (the mapping that binds the mesh to the skeleton used as the animation proxy) so I'd look there first. You *may* be able to fix it in C4D by re-painting your bind weight maps manually for each joint and joint series.

Comment: Please tell me if you found a solution to this. It's driving me nuts